# Use ratio test to test for convergence or divergence

Tags: limits, derivatives, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have online hw and it tells me if my answer is correct or not. It said that my answer for this problem is incorrect:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Also I might be asking alot of these questions later since I am new to this concept.

Comment: Note that first equality is incrrect. The sum is not equal to this limit, rather, this limit is going to tell you if the sum converges or not.

Answer (score 4):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}/a_n<1$ the series converges,  if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}/a_n>1$ the series diverges.

The test gives no information if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}/a_n=1$.

Comment: OH thank u so much!

Comment: Your quite welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes.

1. The series in not equal to the limit in the first line.
2. Limit of the ratio of  in the second line is probably from de l'Hospital's rule, but $n$ is discrete.
3. If this limits is equal to 2, the series diverges (d'Alembert test).